# How would I go about creating content on a unique url page that is not created until an image is clicked?

Tags: php

I've created a simple website on which you can register, then log-in and be able to upload images which are then displayed on the index page. Each displayed image leads to a url

uploads/".$imagePath."

which displays the image in it's full size in a new url. Unfortunately that url only contains the image but I would like to include image information, header, footer, etc. Obviously if the url led to a page that I have created, I could simply include header,footer and the stuff I need but since it's unique for every image, I have absolutely no idea what to do about it. Here's my code

```
echo                "<br>"
                    .$getResult['name'].'<br><br>'
                    ."<a href='uploads/".$imagePath."'>".'<img class="uploadedImg" src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image" /></a>'."<br><br>"
                    .$getResult['description']."<br><br>"
                    .$getResult['date']."<br><br>"
                    .$getResult['author']."<br><br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

For each image, instead of giving image as hyperlink to large image, give a hyperlink to php file as follows:

```
<a href="imageinfo.php?id=<?php echo $image_id;?>">
<?php echo "<img class='uploadedImg' src=$image alt='Random image' />"?>
</a>
```

Along with the 'imageinfo.php' file, pass unique id of the large image information row, that is stored in database, which you are planning to include in your header and footer.
In the 'imageinfo.php' file you can access this $image_id as $_GET['image_id']. Using which you can get the data from database and display.
So all the images will be hyperlinked to same 'imageinfo.php' file but based on the id send with it the Large image and its associated header and footer can be fetched from database and displayed.

Happy Coding!